# Getting hold of old wxPython (3.x) for macOS (pref. using brew or pip)

Tags: macos, pip, wxpython, homebrew, legacy

Since the new release of Project Phoenix / wxPython 4.0, all old packages seems to be gone from pypi as well as wxpython's own snapshots.

I've (without success) been trying to figure out how to get hold of a 3.0.x version of wxmac/wxpython that I can install via pip or brew.

*(I'd prefer not to download a .dmg via sourceforge)*

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the old versions of wxPython Classic on SourceForge where they've always been:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/

wxPython 4 is based on Phoenix and is the only pip installable version of wxPython. There is no previous version of wxPython that is pip installable. The wxPython 3.0.2.0 version is Classic only. I believe wxPython 4 is 3.0.3.0

Comment: Thx Mike! I thought sourceforge was now all malware so I didn't dare to pull or install from those binaries.

Comment: Any suggestion on best way to setup a 32-bit python environment (on mac) incl. the legacy wxPython? conda, virtualenv, VM?

Comment: SourceForge isn't completely crap yet. I think I had an old 64-bit version of wxPython 3.0.2 on my Mac for a while. I just downloaded the cocoa build and installed it

Comment: I believe conda is also a viable option, although I don't know if they do 32-bit